# How to install the same game in a Switch console with a parent account and a second Switch console with a child account?

Tags: nintendo-switch, nintendo-account

I have:

- A Nintendo Switch with both an adult account and a child account
- A Nintendo Switch Lite with only a child account (the same child account also present in the first console)

I actually have two related questions (both are about installing the same game in two different consoles):

1. I've found that the child account on the second console has to pay again for any game in the eShop already purchased with the adult account in the first console. How do I share eShop games with the child account or console?
2. I've found that if the second console (with only the child account) downloads a free game, I can't download the same free game with my regular first Nintendo Switch which has both accounts. Even if I access the eShop with the parent account, it just says the free game is already "purchased" and there are no buttons to download the game from the eShop in this first console. I don't understand why this happens, since I'm using both a different console and a different account (the parent account) to the one that downloaded the free game in the other console (the child account), but anyway, how can I get around this problem?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

1) Generally, a game can only be played if an account that purchased the game is present on the console. So, unless you install the parent account on the Switch Lite, it should not be possible to download or start any games purchased with the parent account. Even if the parent account is present on the Switch Lite, other limitations (such as a network connection being required) may apply. Without these restrictions, it would be extremely easy to give random people access to a free library of games by abusing the parent/child account system, and Nintendo obviously can't allow that.

2) In the Switch's main menu, scroll through the list of games all the way to the right and click the round button that says "All Software". Then, scroll all the way to the bottom and click on "Redownload Software". Choose the child account, and you should see a list of all games unlocked with that account along with the option to download them again.

Comment: Hello. Thanks for your reply. Nintendo system of downloading stuff is really convoluted. Why can't they add a Download button for free games in the eShop no matter if the title was already downloaded before or not? (just like in a smartphone or tablet)

Comment: “Obviously” is misspelled.